How to create Loop Sculpt Brush
How could I create loop from this sculpt. I sculpted this on plane, tried to make VDM Brush in Blender, however it only can work on plane? I couldn't figure it out. This is leather stitch on edge of sword handle.
On second picture is what I am trying to achieve. Thanks!


